# Placing 3d object in direction of camera if Trackable is not a plane

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I'm trying to attach objects to anchors of type `Point` not a `Plane`.

How could I rotate figurine to stand vertically and looking into camera direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answer is still relevant because the question was asked 11 months ago.

Since you did not specify what language you are using, I am assuming you are using Unity and C#. You could change the default orientation and position of your model in Unity editor, this way, when you instantiate the model, it will be rendered with that default orientation and position. Or in Unity script, you can use the this API [Transform.Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) to rotate the model around any axis you want, based on the picture, you want to rotate around x axis, then y axis (Note that rotations are not commutative, so rotating around x then y is not the same as rotating around y then x). Additionally you can use this API [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) to make the object face in the direction of the transform passed to it.